# web2py MENU Where in bootstrap styles can I change that text of menu items will no longer be uppercase?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web2py

Out of the box web2py MENU and bootstrap styles for nav, navbar-nav etc. automatically transform text of the menu item to uppercase. I have seen in the source of a page that there the text is still the same as in the code in menu.py where the items were defined.

I have also found quite a number of occurrences of text-transform:uppercase in the style sheets, and have tried to change these to text-transform:capitalize, but the menu-items are still displayed in uppercase.

Also, there is a warning that these are generated sources, and that I should not edit them as they will be overwritten when these files are re-generated.

It is nice that web2py provide so many nice things out-of-the box, but I would appreciate any help on how to get rid of all uppercase in the text of menu-items.

Answer (score 1):

The current web2py scaffolding app UI is based on the [Bootswatch Sandstone](https://bootswatch.com/sandstone/) theme. Its CSS file is `/static/css/bootstrap.min.css`. To override the uppercase transform style in the menu, add the following rule somewhere *after* the `bootstrap.min.css` file is loaded (e.g., in `web2py-bootstrap3.css` or in your own custom CSS file):

```
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Comment: Very helpful answer! Thank you very much.